# Get SharePoint group permissions level name based on group name Using SharePoint Rest API

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, permissions, rest, provider-hosted-app

I am trying to get SharePoint User group permissions (Ex: Read, Contribute) based on the group name using SharePoint Rest API. My goal is to get the permission level of the group and disable features on our custom app based on the permission levels. I have tried the below url to get the group properties but couldn't get the permission level of the group. Could anyone please guide me on how to get the User group permissions.

Options Tried:

URL = http://Servename/Site/api/web/SiteGroups/getByName('group name')

Comment: Check this link about [REST API in SharePoint - Group properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432.aspx#bk_Group). I can't elaborate an answer, hence my comment, but this could be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The below endpoint will return all the groups along with the roles assigned.

```
<site>/_api/Web/RoleAssignments?$expand=Member,RoleDefinitionBindings
```

Reference: https://sshareasolutions.com/2017/09/27/display-permissions-for-any-site-or-list-using-rest-api/